# On what Sirius XM station would I hear these songs?

Tags: radio

Most any deftones song, or My Name is Human by Highly Suspect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The band would most likely appear on the [Octane](https://m.siriusxm.com/octane) station as it plays contemporary rock.

I've done some more digging and Highly Suspect have [appeared on the Octane station](https://blog.siriusxm.com/highly-suspect-premieres-new-song-my-name-is-human-exclusively-on-octane/).